# How to accept extra params in open syscall?

Tags: linux, filesystems, kernel, virtual-file-system

I am developing a filesystem module for linux as a project. I want the files to be protected passwords. I want that `open()` accepts a password in addition to the filepath and mode. But I cannot find clear documentation on how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Create own `open` function which accept password, check the password and then call system `open`.

Comment: Password checking is not a user level task. It must be done by kernel with the help of some data stored in inode. Basically inode is required to authenticate the password.

Comment: @MahekShamsukha, this is your task. I give you idea how to have one more parameter. About the rest better ask here: https://stackoverflow.com/